# C# SqlCommand - cannot use parameters for column names, how to resolve?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005

Is there any way how to do that? This does not work:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT @slot FROM Users WHERE name=@name; ");
prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", name);
prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("slot", slot);
```

The only thing I can think of is to use SP and declare and set the variable for the column. Seems to me a bit ackward.

Comment: Consider that your `Users` table is denormalized, hence the solution to your problem would involve resolving the design to fifth normal form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do this in regular SQL - if you must have configurable column names (or table name, for that matter), you must use dynamic SQL - there is no other way to achieve this.

```
string sqlCommandStatement =  
   string.Format("SELECT {0} FROM dbo.Users WHERE name=@name", "slot");
```

and then use the `sp_executesql` stored proc in SQL Server to execute that SQL command (and specify the other parameters as needed).

Dynamic SQL has its pros and cons - read the ultimate article on [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) expertly written by SQL Server MVP Erland Sommarskog.

Comment: The example code you give above doesn't demonstrate dynamic SQL, it just shows the use of the string.Format function. As written it's confusing.

Comment: @Yellowfog: now take this string that's been formatted and use it in a call to "sp_executesql" and you have your dynamic SQL.....

Comment: Well, you have your SQL, but it's not particularly 'dynamic', is my point. As I understand this, it refers to SQL which is constructed on the database side of things, not the webserver side. Or am I unusual in taking the term that way?

Comment: @Yellowfog: "dynamic SQL" is dynamic, when you "string together" your SQL command and then call `sp_executesql` to execute it - that's all

Comment: If you look at the actual reading you cite, below the line "There are two main roads to go, and then there are forks and sub-forks" you'll note that your example falls under 1(ii) whereas 2(ii) is the home of dynamic SQL. This corresponds with my understanding of the term.

Answer (score 13):

As has been mentioned, you cannot parameterise the fundamental query, so you will have to build the query itself at runtime. You should **white-list** the input of this, to prevent injection attacks, but fundamentally:

```
// TODO: verify that "slot" is an approved/expected value
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT [" + slot +
           "] FROM Users WHERE name=@name; ")
prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", name);
```

This way `@name` is still parameterised etc.