# DataAdapter Sql Query with parameters - c#

Tags: c#

Code below is working properly and view all matches by search **in** column.

```
string sql = "SELECT car, model, year FROM store WHERE" + column + "LIKE " + search + "'";
```

Now adding parameters in query. Not working. It doesn't display **search** in **column**. Only display all rows in column, if search column of column ( 1 = 1)

```
    public int SearchCar(MainStore searchCars)
    {
            string connection = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection);
            string sql = "SELECT car, model, year FROM store WHERE @column like @search '";
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);

            sdt.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@column", "%" + searchCars.GetCombo());
            sdt.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search", "%" + searchCars.GetSearch());

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
     }
```

What could possible be the answer to get it search within specific column?

Comment: can you post end - end code from connection opening to connection closing? or explain what is "search", "sdt"?

Comment: It doesn't work Alexander.

Comment: You can't do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330343/c-sharp-sqlcommand-cannot-use-parameters-for-column-names-how-to-resolve  You _can_ use a 'hybrid' method of your two samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it as follows so as to not parameterize the column name:

```
public int SearchCar(MainStore searchCars)
    {
            string connection = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection);
            string sql = string.Format("SELECT car, model, year FROM store WHERE {0} like @search", search.GetCombo());
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);

           // sdt.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@column", "%" + search.GetCombo());
            sdt.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search", "%" + search.GetSearch());

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
     }
```

Also, you've got an extra quote at the end of your query:
`like @search '";`

Comment: I discovered a new issue. When the combobox is not selected, then a catch error appears. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'like'

Comment: You're going to have to handle the case where it is not selected. I'm guessing `search.GetCombo()` returns null if it isn't selected. For example, you could try throwing an alert in case nothing is selected.  `var columnName = search.GetCombo();`  `if (columnName == null) {`  `\\Show validation message`  `return;`  `}`

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this

```
 private static void Select() {

       string cmdStr = "SELECT FirstName, LastName, Telephone FROM Person WHERE FirstName = @FirstName";

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, connection)) {

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", "John");

            connection.Open();

            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read()) {

                string output = "First Name: {0} \t Last Name: {1} \t Phone: {2}";

                Console.WriteLine(output, reader["FirstName"], reader["LastName"], reader["Telephone"]);

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: That's not correct at all. I'm using SqlDataAdapter and combobox.

Comment: Sorry i did not understand you question