# C# - Using A String Passed Through A Parameter In String

Tags: c#

I want to achieve this:

```
public void SQLInfo(string column)
{
    SqlConnection Connect = new SqlConnection(
        "Server=server;Database=db;User ID=user;Password=pass;");
    Connect.Open();        
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(
        "select distinct [column] from [dbo].[ServerAttributes]");
    SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
}
```

I failed to find documentation on this. Is there any specific method to use a string passed through a parameter within a string? For example, in Powershell you could use the '$' to denote a variable within a string. "This is the **$server** you're working on."

Comment: You most likely ***really*** don't want to do this since it's a perfect way to introduce Sql Injection if `column` can be provided via user input (and it probably can).

Comment: You're looking for the wonders of string concatenation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# SqlCommand - cannot use parameters for column names, how to resolve?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330343/c-sharp-sqlcommand-cannot-use-parameters-for-column-names-how-to-resolve)

Comment: @DavidL I don't want it to be provided via user input because I'm trying to automate this process. I'm only using a handful of columns that will remain fixed unless changes are required.

Comment: If SQLInfo is called in a loop, use a StringBuilder ... to credit @DavidL ... if anyone inputs "1;delete *" for your column input, you're in for some serious crying time.

Comment: If you have C#6 you can use an interpolated string `$"select distinct [{column}] from [dbo].[ServerAttributes]"`

Comment: if you are using c# 6 put a $ in front of the string and add {} around column - $"select distinct [{column}] from bla bla bla"; and that's the wonders of string interpolation ;-)

Comment: @Paurian: That has nothing to do with a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can using `string.Format()` like

```
public void SQLInfo(string column)
        {
  string query = string.Format("select distinct {0} from [dbo].[ServerAttributes]", column);
  SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query);
  SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
```

Answer (score 0):

When using  C# lower than 6 use string formatter

```
string command = string.Format("SELECT DISTINCT[{0}] FROM[dbo].[ServerAttributes]", column);
```

For C#6 , you have string literal operator `$` it is translated to the same logic as in previous version , but makes the code more readble.

```
string command = $"SELECT DISTINCT[{column}] FROM[dbo].[ServerAttributes];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string interpolation if you are using C# 6

```
public void SQLInfo(string column)
{
    SqlConnection Connect = new SqlConnection(
        "Server=server;Database=db;User ID=user;Password=pass;");
    Connect.Open();        
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(
        $"select distinct [{column}] from [dbo].[ServerAttributes]");
    SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
}
```

Otherwise use string.Format

```
public void SQLInfo(string column)
{
    SqlConnection Connect = new SqlConnection(
        "Server=server;Database=db;User ID=user;Password=pass;");
    Connect.Open();        
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(
        string.Format("select distinct [{0}] from [dbo].[ServerAttributes]",column));
    SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
}
```

**Note** If you're going to do something like this would suggest at least checking to make sure the string isn't introducing the '[' character

```
column = column.Remove("]");
```