# Add quotes around SQL parameter value?

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net, sql-injection

I'm unsure if I'm supposed to add single quotes `''` around an SQL parameter when it's a string value that is already populated with data. My thinking is I don't because by using the `OracleParameter` constructor, it'll automagically get it's data type changed to string.

Specifically, should I be doing this: `'@c'` over just `@c` when doing this: `SELECT @c FROM Dual` when `@c` is a string already when placed into the `OracleParameter` constructor?

```
string calcDateFormat = "Some Data";

try
{
    string sql = "SELECT @c ColumnName FROM Dual";
    // Or should it be this
    string sql = "SELECT '@c' ColumnName FROM Dual";

    using(OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(sql, this.Connection))
    {
        OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(command);
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("@c", OracleDbType.Varchar2, calcDateFormat, ParameterDirection.Output));
        DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(dataset);
        return dataset;
    }
}
catch (OracleException ex)
{
    throw ...
}

// SELECT => 
//        Column: ColumnName
//        Row:    Some Data
```

Comment: This might be one of those try it and see situations :)

Comment: No, you don't need to add quotes, but I think that this code will never return anything in your parameter. At least you need to define the ParameterDirection to Output

Comment: I do not think you can parameterize the column names in that way - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330343/c-sharp-sqlcommand-cannot-use-parameters-for-column-names-how-to-resolve

Comment: @PaulF Didn't mean to `SELECT` the column name, but some arbitrary data. I've edited my question.

Comment: I still don't think it would work - but cannot be sure - as has already been suggested - try it & see, you are doing a select so shouldn't accidentally mess the database. It probably needs a comma after the parameter if followed by a column name.

Comment: The point that I don't understand is why you need to call this when you already know the constant value returned by the query. My Oracle knowledge is rusty

Comment: @Steve That is a separate problem I **completely** agree with. I'm refactoring the code and might just do that. I would still like my question answered as I'm curious.

Comment: I am not sure if that syntax could work with Oracle. Testing something like that with SQL Server gives syntax error. Usually parameters cannot be used where a column name is expected (as after a SELECT statement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no need to add quotes as this code below will work just fine,

```
 string sql = "SELECT @c ColumnName FROM Dual";
```

The reason is if you write '@c' it will search for the matching parameter name in the place you are declaring the parameters and it wont match the query would break.

Comment: What if the query involves something more complicated like this? `SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE SomeColumn IN (:alot)` where `:alot` has to be `'one','two','three'`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can keep it as just `string sql = "SELECT @c FROM Dual";` without the single quotes. That is at least how I write my SQL queries in PHP. I don't know however if the rules are different for C# and Oracle.

Your best chance of answering your question is by trying out both methods and see what happens.