# update statement not updating data in db

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core

I am trying to update the data using an `UPDATE` statement. I am not getting any run time errors. However, no data is being updated in the database. Looks like something is missing in the `WHERE` clause.

```
try
{
    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RL_InventoryConnection"])) /*"*/
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            con.Open();

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE vendormaster SET vendor_name = @vendor_name, vendor_contact_Name1 = @vendor_contact_Name1, vendor_contact_phone1 = @vendor_contact_phone1, vendor_contact_email1 = @vendor_contact_email1, vendor_contact_Name2 = @vendor_contact_Name2, vendor_contact_phone2 = @vendor_contact_phone2, vendor_contact_email2 = @vendor_contact_email2, vendor_pan = @vendor_pan, vendor_gst = @vendor_gst, vendor_address = @vendor_address, vendor_pincode = @vendor_pincode, vendor_city = @vendor_city, vendor_country = @vendor_country WHERE vendor_name like '%@vendor_name%'; ", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vendor_name", getvendorname);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vendor_contact_Name1", getcontactperson1);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vendor_contact_phone1", getcontactphone1);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vendor_contact_email1", getcontactemail1);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vendor_contact_Name2", getcontactperson2);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vendor_contact_phone2", getcontactphone2);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vendor_contact_email2", getpersonemail2);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vendor_pan", getvendorPan);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vendor_gst", getvendorgst);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vendor_address", getvendoraddress);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vendor_pincode", getpincode);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vendor_city", getcity);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vendor_country", getcountry);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }


}

catch (Exception ex)
{ 
    throw ex;
}
```

Comment: Should look more like `WHERE vendor_name like '%' + @vendor_name + '%'`. But you should rethink you design a like in the where clause looks crazy. Try to get somethink more identifying then the name. An artificial unique id like any other system for example.

Comment: Other side note- You have variables starting with 'get' in their name?

Comment: Rafl 1) Thanks you for your feedback. I tried WHERE vendor_name like '%' @vendor_name  '%' and it worked for me. there is auto generated primary key in the db but in the front-end we are not appending it anywhere.

2) yes, i am using get in the variable name. what issue/problem will it cause?

I am new into programming, so not familiar with most of the rules.

Comment: 1.) Then the key seems useless. Return it and use it. Your risiking currently updating the wrong thing (or even multiple uninvolved rows) 2.) No functional problem just a readability thing with calling it "getX". Something called get implies a method call to everyone even just slightly into programming reading it.

Comment: Why not at the very least do `WHERE vendor_name = @vendor_name`? Side note: `if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)` is unnecessary, of course it's closed because you just created it. And this is completely wrong `catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }` it will wipe the stack trace. Instead do `catch (Exception ex) { throw; }` or remove the `catch`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add quotes around SQL parameter value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50452617/add-quotes-around-sql-parameter-value)